# How to get iPhone users to see my Caller ID info?

Tags: iphone, ios, caller-id

We have a Google My Business listing (https://g.page/freelensiacorporate?gm) with a phone number. So, when someone calls us with their Android, they will see the caller ID info like phone number and our business name (Freelensia Corporate) even if we are not in their contact list.

Is there anything we can do to get the iPhone's users to see the same Caller ID info when they call us?

We are located in Vietnam if that is relevant in any case.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I doubt this will happen. Apple is not going to force-subscribe its users to a Google list.

Comment: Well it could be an Apple list. Is there something like that? I tried creating an Apple ID with my business phone number but got no good results.

Comment: I don't know of any such structure for iOS